# How can I replace all instances of a letter and decimal combination greater than a predefined value

Tags: batch-file, replace

I am trying to search through text and find every instance of "Z" followed by a number.  If the number is 40 or higher, then it will be replaced with 32.

So for example

- N170G00*Z58*
- N280G81X9.1787Y15.1981*Z2.3803*R4.6F.75L0.0
- N300G00*Z15.0*
- N580G03X-12.125Y6.7311*Z52.775*I-12.5J6.7311F35.0

Would produce

- N170G00*Z32*
- N280G81X9.1787Y15.1981*Z2.3803*R4.6F.75L0.0
- N300G00*Z15.0*
- N580G03X-12.125Y6.7311*Z32*I-12.5J6.7311F35.0

We are only looking at and changing the Z values.

I have tried with the following code, but it removes all Z values instead.
the "%VarOne%%MS201%" is just the file I have previously output, that I am using as a source.

```
set "INTEXTFILE=%VarOne%%MS201%"
for /f "delims=Z*" %%a in ('type "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET s=%%a
     IF s GTR Z40 SET s=!s:Z32!
     echo !s!>>new.txt
)
```

I need to do this with other values as well (any Y value over 40 needs changed to "Y40"), so hopefully, the solution is expandable and understandable by me.  I am fully aware that I do not fully know what I am doing, but I am trying.

Comment: open cmd.exe and read the output of `if /?` and `set /?`. Within batch, comparitors GTR LSS EQU etc are only accurate for integers, not strings. `Set /?` contains information on the syntax options for performing substring modification, which you will need to utilise to seperate the integer in your string that follows `z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is using the batch/JScript hybrid [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) with the command line:

```
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "Z(?:[1-9][0-9]{2,}|[4-9][0-9])(?:\.[0-9]+)?" "Z32" /F "%VarOne%%MS201%" /O New.txt
```

There could be used `-` instead of `New.txt` to do the replaces directly in file with name defined by `%VarOne%%MS201%`.

`jrepl.bat` is referenced here with the path of the batch file containing this command line and the definitions of the environment variables `VarOne` and `MS201` which means `jrepl.bat` must be in same directory as the batch file.

The search expression `Z(?:[1-9][0-9]{2,}|[4-9][0-9])(?:\.[0-9]+)?` means:

`Z` ... find first case-sensitive this letter.

`(?:`...`)` ... is a non-marking group used here for an **OR** expression.

`[1-9][0-9]{2,}` ... there must be after `Z` a digit in range `1` to `9` with at least two or more digits in range `0` to `9`. So this expression matches numbers in range `100` to `999999999` and even higher numbers.

`|` ... means **OR** as a second expression is needed for numbers lower than `100` after `Z`.

`[4-9][0-9]` ... matches a number with exactly two digits whereby the first digit must be in range `4` to `9` and the second digit can be in range `0` to `9`. So this expression matches numbers in range `40` to `99`.

`(?:`...`)?` ... that is once again a non-marking group used here to apply the multiplier `?` on the entire expression inside the group which means applied zero or exactly once. In other words the expression inside this group with multiplier `?` matches *optionally* also a string.

`\.[0-9]+` ... matches a dot escaped with a backslash to be interpreted as literal character and one or more digits in range `0` to `9`. This *optionally* applied expression matches the decimal point and the post comma digits of a floating point value.

For a replacement of all `Z` values with value `32` or higher the group with the **OR** expression must be extended by one more expression:

```
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "Z(?:[1-9][0-9]{2,}|[4-9][0-9]|3[2-9])(?:\.[0-9]+)?" "Z32" /F "%VarOne%%MS201%" /O New.txt
```

`|3[2-9]` ... is a third **OR** expression matching numbers in range `32` to `39`.

So the three expressions in the **OR** group match numbers `100` or higher, `40` to `99` and `32` to `39` as integers or as floating point values with a decimal point and one or more decimal places with the optionally applied expression in second non-marking group.

Comment: That is so much to take in, but you did a very good job explaining what each value did in the code.  Thanks, this helped tremendously!